# How to connect internet to android emulator?

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-emulator-plugin

Hi I am using HVGA Emulator with platform 4.4, I have internet connection in my computer but when I am trying access internet from my emulator it is not connecting. I have already given the permissions in manifest.xml like

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

But still it is not connecting. it is showing "Unfortunately Browser has been stopped". Why ?
Any suggestions.

Else please suggest good versions of emulator which can access internet and targeted from lower version.

Comment: have to tested internet access in emulator's default browser?

Comment: try to open www.google.com in your emulator's browser

Comment: yes try browser if not work means set ip in emmulater

Comment: Yes, I tested in emulator's default browser. Even I tried with www.google.com It is showing "Unfortunately Browser has been stopped".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your problem is occurring when you're on a wireless network and you have a LAN card installed, the issue is that the emulator tries to obtain its DNS settings from that LAN card. Not a problem when you're connected via that LAN, but utterly useless if you're on a wireless connection. I noticed this when I was on my laptop.

So, how to fix? Simple: Disable your LAN card. Really. Just go to your Network connections, find your LAN card, right click it and choose disable. Now try your emulator. If you're like me, it suddenly ... works!

Comment: When I disable my LAN network will I able to access internet in my computer ? If not with out connection in my computer how can emulator can access internet?

Comment: Thanks for replay.. I tried with your suggestion it is not working. I got got same problem